# psnup can't open config file paper.cfg

Tags: paper-size, postscript

I'm using Cygwin's `psnup`.  Even issuing `psnup --help` generates the error `can't open config file paper.cfg`.  The only thing I've found online about this is [this message](https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2014-April/035154.html):

```
A missing file is

    texmf-var/psutils/paper.cfg

with contents (3 lines)

    # default papersize
    p a4
    # more comment

where a4 may be letter or others.
```

A web search yields many possible [paths for paper.cfg](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22psutils%2Fpaper.cfg%22), e.g., [texmf-config/psutils/paper.cfg](http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/doc/latex-overview/index.html).

A Cygwin package search for `paper.cfg` yields [/usr/share/texmf-dist/psutils/paper.cfg](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Ftexlive-collection-fontutils%2Ftexlive-collection-fontutils-20210118-1&grep=psutils) for for the `texlive-collection-fontutils` package.  My installation doesn't have a folder `/usr/share/texmf-dist/psutils`, but I created both it and `paper.cfg` therein, containing the 3 lines above.  However, `psnup` still yields the above error.

How do I determine the location in which `psnup` expects `paper.cfg`?

Comment: does it look for the cfg at all if you use `-P a4` on the commandline?

Comment: I get the same error with both `psnup -P letter --help` and `psnup -Pletter --help`.  Same thing if I replace `letter` with `a4` in both.

Comment: sorry then I don't know. the file is in texmf-dist/psnutils/paper.cfg and works for me (using texlive 2021 pretest on cygwin) but I have not used psnup since last century so I'm not sure where it is looking for anything these days

Comment: OK, thanks, David.

Comment: I have cygwin and there is a cygwin supplied psnup in /usr/bin that gives the error you state even for `psnup --help`  I use the texlive 2020 (and 2021 pretest) cygwin texlive builds installed from tug in /usr/local/texlive/2020 and they come with a psnup, I looked in the sources and there are comments that the code changed so that it searches the TeX input  tree for the default paper size so I am not sure where the original in ./usr/bin/psnup is looking but it does not work for me either. `$ type -all psnup
psnup is /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-cygwin/psnup
psnup is /usr/bin/psnup`

Comment: Thanks again, David.  Even though the solution is unknown, I learned about the `type` command from your comment.  Very useful.

Comment: a workaround is to put the `paper.cfg` file in the cwd; not a general solution, which I may try to figure out.